# Mysql Query Limit Running Slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to figure out why is one of my query slow using limit and how I can fix it.

Table size: 2.8M

Indexes in this order:

- user_id => transactions_user_id_foreign
- service => service_idx
- type => type_idx
- currency => currency_idx
- status => status_idx
- created_at => created_at_idx
- currency_id => currency_id_idx
- user_action_id => user_action_id_idx
- provider => provider_idx

Query:

```
select  *
    from  transactions
    where  type = 0
      and  status != '2'
      and  status != '0'
      and  service IN ('credit_card', 'paypal')
      and  created_at >= '2021-09-15 14:04:40'
    order by  id DESC
    limit  200
```

**Explained:**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys                  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                   |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transactions | NULL       | range | service,type,status,created_at | type | 1       | NULL | 506082 |     0.05 | Using index condition; Using where; Backward index scan |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+------+-------
```

Now it takes around 4seconds. If I will remove the limit it takes 0.03seconds.

I tried more combinations of indexes but without success.

Comment: Change `and status != '2' and status != '0` to `and status not in (2,0)` does it make a difference ?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM transactions; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE transactions;  Positive side effect, indexes will be refreshed.

Comment: Please show us both of the complete versions of the query - with and without LIMIT and the EXPLAIN for each.

Comment: How many different values are in `status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest two indexes.  (The Optimizer will pick the one it prefers.)

```
INDEX(type, service, created_at)  -- in this order
INDEX(type, created_at)  -- in this order
```

And remove the now-redundant

```
INDEX(type)
```

Comment: After adding the first index as you suggested the Query took 0.0028 seconds. Thanks Rick. But why status was not included in the index?

Comment: @raduparaleste - `NOT`, `!=`, `OR` usually cannot use indexes. Hence my Comment.  If, for example, the only value you are checking for is `status = 1` (and you used that instead of the `!=` tests), then `status could be included early in each index.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: if I have more columns, lets 6 columns in where clause, sometimes I need to use 3, sometimes 4, sometimes 5 columns. In this case I have to create an index for each case? 
index1: column1,column2,column3
index2: column1,column2,column3,,column4, etc ? or is enough to create only one index with all 6 columns? (using the same order of columns).

Comment: @raduparaleste - `INDEX(a,b)` is useless if you do not mention `a` in the `WHERE` clause.  That is, only the leftmost columns of an index are useful.  Hence, you may need more than one index.  Provide a list of "likely" `WHERE` clauses, I will provide you with a small set of `INDEXes` that will do a "pretty good" job.